# Inhertitance in hsql database using jakarta

Tags: database

we are developing a persistence system.
We have to use inhertitance for create a superclass call User and two subclasses: Teacher and Member.

User definition:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USUARIOS")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="TYPE", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING,length=20)
@DiscriminatorValue("Usuario")
public class UsuarioDAO implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String nickname;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private String fechaNacimiento;
}
```

Member definition:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SOCIOS")
@DiscriminatorValue("Socio")
public class SocioDAO extends UsuarioDAO{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "socio")
    private Collection<RegistroDAO> registrosAClase;
```

}

Teacher definition:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PROFESORES")
@DiscriminatorValue("Profesor")
public class ProfesorDAO extends UsuarioDAO{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="profesor")
    private Collection<ActividadDeportivaDAO> actividadesPropuestas;
}
```

Getters and setters implements.

The problem is when the DB is created, in inhertitance classes we dont see the class's attributes, only de superclass's attributes.

This is the sript generated.

CREATE TABLE ACTIVIDADES (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, COSTO REAL, DESCRIPCION VARCHAR(255), DURACION INTEGER, FECHAALTA VARCHAR(255), FECHAFINALIZACION VARCHAR(255), NOMBRE VARCHAR(255), ID_PROFESOR BIGINT, PRIMARY KEY (ID))
CREATE TABLE CLASES (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, FECHAALTA VARCHAR(255), FECHAINICIO VARCHAR(255), HORAINICIO VARCHAR(255), NOMBRE VARCHAR(255), SOCIOSMAXIMOS INTEGER, SOCIOSMINIMOS INTEGER, URL VARCHAR(255), ID_ACTIVIDAD BIGINT, PRIMARY KEY (ID))
CREATE TABLE USUARIOS (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, TYPE VARCHAR(20), APELLIDO VARCHAR(255), EMAIL VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, FECHANACIMIENTO VARCHAR(255), NICKNAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, NOMBRE VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (ID))
CREATE TABLE PROFESORES (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID))
CREATE TABLE REGISTROS (COSTO REAL, FECHAREGISTRO VARCHAR(255), ID_CLASE BIGINT NOT NULL, ID_SOCIO BIGINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID_CLASE, ID_SOCIO))
CREATE TABLE SOCIOS (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID))
ALTER TABLE USUARIOS ADD CONSTRAINT UNQ_USUARIOS_3 UNIQUE (EMAIL)
ALTER TABLE USUARIOS ADD CONSTRAINT UNQ_USUARIOS_5 UNIQUE (NICKNAME)
ALTER TABLE ACTIVIDADES ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ACTIVIDADES_ID_PROFESOR FOREIGN KEY (ID_PROFESOR) REFERENCES USUARIOS (ID)
ALTER TABLE CLASES ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CLASES_ID_ACTIVIDAD FOREIGN KEY (ID_ACTIVIDAD) REFERENCES ACTIVIDADES (ID)
ALTER TABLE PROFESORES ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PROFESORES_ID FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES USUARIOS (ID)
ALTER TABLE REGISTROS ADD CONSTRAINT FK_REGISTROS_ID_SOCIO FOREIGN KEY (ID_SOCIO) REFERENCES USUARIOS (ID)
ALTER TABLE REGISTROS ADD CONSTRAINT FK_REGISTROS_ID_CLASE FOREIGN KEY (ID_CLASE) REFERENCES CLASES (ID)
ALTER TABLE SOCIOS ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SOCIOS_ID FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES USUARIOS (ID)
CREATE TABLE SEQUENCE (SEQ_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, SEQ_COUNT NUMERIC(38), PRIMARY KEY (SEQ_NAME))
INSERT INTO SEQUENCE VALUES('SEQ_GEN',0)
COMMIT

Example: when we put a teacher we dont see the actividadPropuesta attribute.

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags here. Only tag the RDBMS you are really using.

Comment: Also, it seems you should be tagging your programming language, which you have completely omitted.